# javascript changing between three images on a button click

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var trafficlights = ['redlight.png','yellowlight.png','greenlight.png'];
            var num = 1

            function lightsequence() {
                document.getElementById('light').src = trafficlights[num];
                num = num + 1;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="light" src="redlight.png">
        <button onclick="lightsequence()">Change Lights</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have written that piece of code and the images change in order one by one each time I click the button but I cannot think of how to reverse the order if I keep clicking, i.e. traffic lights red yellow green yellow red etc. each time I click. I am unfamiliar with jQuery so would like to not use them ideally but if someone can explain it fully with jQuery in working it will have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) is very convenient in such cases:

```
document.getElementById('light').src = trafficlights[num++ % trafficlights.length];
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var trafficlights = [
 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Red.png', 
 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Yellow.png', 
 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Green.png'
];
var num = 1

function lightsequence() {
  document.getElementById('light').src = trafficlights[num++ % trafficlights.length];
}
```

```html
<img id="light" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Red.png">
<button onclick="lightsequence()">Change Lights</button>
```

Comment: this works fine but jumps from grenn back upto red where as i want it to change back to red going through yellow

Comment: yeah i fixed it i just had to add in another yellow image on the end of the varible container

Comment: I have now done this to the code and fixed the original issue but i want to know if there is a way to get the light sequence to run once automatically each time the button is clicked and pause slightly longer on red than the other colours?

Answer (score 0):

Change Lights

```js
function lightsequence(){
  
document.getElementById("light").src

if(document.getElementById("light").src=="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Red.png"){
     document.getElementById("light").src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Yellow.png"
    
}else if(document.getElementById("light").src=="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Yellow.png"){
   document.getElementById("light").src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Green.png"
                         
}else{
   document.getElementById("light").src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Red.png"
      
      }
}
```

```html
<img id="light" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/48x48/Circle_Red.png">
<button onclick="lightsequence()">Change Lights</button>
```